# Is it possible to run osmdroid in a java swing application

Tags: java, osmdroid, mapsforge

Basically I need a java swing or javafx component that supports online map sources (googlemaps & openstreetmap) as well as offline map sources.

I found that [mapsforge](https://github.com/mapsforge/mapsforge) can do the trick (but it does not support google maps as a source). So I came across [osmdroid library](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid) which replaces the Android's MapView. The thing is that osmdroid supports everything (googlemaps & openstreetmap and offline map sources). And I am wondering if it is possible to use osmdroid in a java swing application (not running on android), running on a desktop.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Osmdroid depends on Android SDK heavilly. So no, it cannot by used without android.